# Retrieve app engine staging bucket name in GCP through terraform

Tags: google-app-engine, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

How to retrieve app engine staging bucket name in terraform ?
I can retrieve app engine default service account as shown below:

```
data "google_app_engine_default_service_account" "app_engine_sv_account" {
  project = var.project_id
}
```

But I did not find any way to retrieve app engine staging bucket using `data` property.